# Different cookie name

Tags: javascript, cookies

[image: Cookie info]

Can red and blue outlined names be different. I have written the code below. Or if there is any better way.

```
set_custom_cookies: function ( cookieName,cookieData,days ) {
    if ( days ) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime( date.getTime()+( days*24*60*60*1000 ) );
        //cookie expiration date
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    } else var expires = "";

    //add cookie info 
    document.cookie = cookieName + "=" +cookieData + expires + "; path=/";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass data to the function `set_custom_cookies()` you send an argument `cookieName`. This is the name of the cookie that you want to change. Call this something else.

`set_custom_cookies("myCustomName", cookieData, days);`

Comment: Hello @display_name. I hope you can see the image Cookie info (image). Can green and red outlined circles have different names? Right now they have same name as the passed cookie params.

Comment: No, that is not possible, @user3386487. Why would you want that?

Comment: Ok thanks! I wanted to call/set the name just like you do with K-V pairs of an array. a different cookie name, a name submitted by user in red circled area and email in the content section. My ignorance :)